# Fitbit - timer - how to show current time on application

Tags: javascript, html, fitbit

I'm trying to use my fitbit to help know how far into my gym I am more easily. Making this more simple so the solution is easier for people to help with.

I'm using a fitbit and some basic JS.

Using the clock API I can create a timer, but not trigger one with a button.

i.e., this does the job.

```
import clock from "clock";
import document from "document";
import { preferences } from "user-settings";
import * as util from "../common/utils";

import { display } from "display";

// Update the clock every minute
clock.granularity = "seconds";

// Get a handle on the <text> element
const ClockLabel = document.getElementById("timeLabel");
const Timer= document.getElementById("timerLabel");
const myButton = document.getElementById("button-1");
myButton.text = "button";

// Update the <text> element every tick with the current time
clock.ontick = (evt) => {
  var Timing = 4*60*60
   let today = evt.date;
  var diff = Timing - ((today - start)/1000 |0);
  let hours  = (diff / 3600) | 0;
  let minutes = ((diff - (hours*3600)) / 60) | 0;
  let seconds = diff - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)| 0;

  console.log("hours:"+hours+", minutes:"+minutes+", seconds:"+seconds);


  let hours = today.getHours();
  let minutes = today.getMinutes();
  let seconds = today.getSeconds();
  if (preferences.clockDisplay === "12h") {
    // 12h format
    hours = hours % 12 || 12;
  } else {
    // 24h format
    hours = util.zeroPad(hours);
  }
  ClockLabel.text = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```

However when firing from a button, it doesn't work whatsoever.

```
myButton.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  var start = Date.now()
//also this doesn't work let today = evt.date;

  myButton.text = "Started";
  
  
  var Timing = 4*60*60;
  var diff = Timing - ((Date.now() - start)/1000 |0);
  let hours  = (diff / 3600) | 0;
  let minutes = ((diff - (hours*3600)) / 60) | 0;
  let seconds = diff - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)| 0;

  console.log("hours:"+hours+", minutes:"+minutes+", seconds:"+seconds);
    ClockLabel.text = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;

});
```

This draws me to the conclusion that using this function is probably a better way forward.

```
function CountDownTimer(duration, granularity) {
  this.duration = duration;
  this.granularity = granularity || 1000;
  this.tickFtns = [];
  this.running = false;
}

CountDownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
  if (this.running) {
    return;
  }
  this.running = true;
  var start = Date.now(),
      that = this,
      diff, obj;

  (function timer() {
    diff = that.duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    if (diff > 0) {
      setTimeout(timer, that.granularity);
    } else {
      diff = 0;
      that.running = false;
    }

    obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
    that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
      ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
    }, that);
  }());
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.onTick = function(ftn) {
  if (typeof ftn === 'function') {
    this.tickFtns.push(ftn);
  }
  return this;
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.expired = function() {
  return !this.running;
};

CountDownTimer.parse = function(seconds) {
  return {
      'hours': (seconds / 3600)|0,
    'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
    'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
  };
};



export default CountDownTimer;
```

Comment: In your formatting function, you should be using `hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;` instead of `hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : 0;` (the same goes for minutes and seconds)

Comment: Yeah my bad, this was a change away from that, i'll change it back soon

Comment: hi your original question asks how to get time, I answered that, _but then you changed the scope to a timer_ please create a new question for the time.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your Question: **how to show current time on application?...** for the most part, your code looks fine.

To get the current time, its the normal `js date` [ref from FitBit](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/device-api/clock/)

#### IMHO you have a couple options `1`) using the `tick` event API or `2`) use sample clock app from Fitbit Studio and customize it with your code.

In the end, I added some custom code at the last to help you update the format/display/labels, please adapt it to your needs..

> **option 1 Tick Event *Approach***: For e.g. **option with [clock face](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/device-api/clock/)** to get the current time you need to use the date API or the the `tick event` which contains the `date object` as the picture, it also saves you battery life!

[image: Tick event for Current date time object in fitbit]

---

> **option 2 Modify Sample *Approach***: Take the [sample getting started app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlV73.png) and *modify* it [ref sample to help you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYzb3.png) and the [below sample](https://dev.fitbit.com/getting-started/)

[image: Fitbit Studio help to create digital clock sample]

```
           1. Recommended: you can follow the sample https://dev.fitbit.com/getting-started/

           2. There are three files you can peek/update/play around 

           3. Move your crunching code here -> Apps>index.js

           4. Plan/put on the UI/Face   ->         Resource>index.gui

           5. Modify styles via css, font etc. here  -> Resource>styles.css


  let day = today.getDate(); // and the get the time from there. or tick event
```

---

## Now your format your time issue

> this below *code also has some boilerplate to wire up* and help you with the display please *modify as per your needs*

```
import clock from "clock";
import document from "document";
import { preferences } from "user-settings";
import * as util from "../common/utils";

//import { me as appbit } from "appbit";
import { display } from "display";
//import * as messaging from "messaging";

// Update/Display the text, get a handle on the <text> element
const timeLabel = document.getElementById("timeLabel");
const dateLabel = document.getElementById("dateLabel");

// just threw this in for your ** Medication.. you need to configure/add it
// const MedicationReminder = document.getElementById("MedicationLabel");


clock.granularity = "seconds";
// Update the <text> element every tick with the current time
clock.ontick = (evt) => {
let today = evt.date;
let hours = today.getHours();

if (preferences.clockDisplay === "12h") {
// 12h format
hours = hours % 12 || 12;
} else {
// 24h format
hours = util.zeroPad(hours);
}

let minutes = util.zeroPad(today.getMinutes());
let seconds = util.zeroPad(today.getSeconds());

let day = util.zeroPad(today.getDate());
let month = util.zeroPad(today.getMonth() + 1);
let year = today.getFullYear();

// update like so
timeLabel.text = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}` ;


  function setDateDisplay(obj, d, m, y, format) {
  
  let date;
  if(format) {
    date = `${m}/${d}/${y}`;
  }
  else {
    date = `${d}/${m}/${y}`;
  }
  
  obj.text = date;
  settings.USDateFormat = format;
  }
```

Comment: sure thing.. hope it helps :)

Comment: Ahh i just realised this doesn't solve the issue haha. I want to make a timer, can i get the specific time at one point as a variable to then set an alarm at X point with the time api? feel like the documention points me back towards using the javascript Date object

Comment: Yeah wasn't looking to make a clock, but a timer, and i'm not sure you can use the clock.ontick to do that?

Comment: you are importing the clock in your code you might as well use it. `your questions asks how to get time, I answered that`. If you want a timer open a new question, I will post code for that.